# Extension Method to an item of a ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, extension-methods, readonly-collection

I have a ReadOnlyCollection of a custom Interface type (IMyInterface). I want to add an extension method to the custom Interface type. However, my extension method is not showing up when I access an item inside the ReadOnlyCollection.
Here's my code :

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string GetValueByName(this IMyInterface myInterface, string myName)
    {
        foreach (var name in myInterface.names) //
        {
            if (myName == name)
                return name;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(myName + " not found.");
    }
}
```

When I try to access it by doing something like,

```
MyMethod[0].<extension method>   //MyMethod returns a ReadOnlyCollection<IMyInterface>
```

The extension method is not showing up in the pop-up available after the MyMethod[0] (in Visual Studio) meaning its not available. What could I possibly be missing? Is it possible to add an extension method for the item in the ReadOnlyCollection?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't included the `using` for the the extension's namespace.

Comment: Wow! I thought Visual Studio will detect that automatically and prompt me to add it.  Didn't realize it was missing the namespace! Thanks @NeilSmith . That worked!

Comment: I wonder why people use extension method for their own class/interface!

Comment: @Yogee How else would you provide the concrete implementation of a method for an interface?

Comment: @Servy That's a good point i never used extension method's in such a way.

Comment: @eranotzap That's what you're doing any time you create an extension method on an interface.  Creating an extension method for a class you have control over the source of is something that can also make sense, but it's a much narrower/unusual situation than for interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I'll turn it into an answer:

You haven't included the `using` statement for your extension's namespace.

For example, if you wrote the extension in `MyNamespace`, you would have to include `using MyNamespace` in the class where you're using the extension.